# Editing Landmark Regions In Vision Kit

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am trying to change the color of lips landmark region to some random RGB value that I have detected using vision kit, Can anyone help me, How can I proceed with my Aim.
I am trying to make lipstick trial app, any help would be appreciated.
**I followed this tutorial** https://medium.com/@kravik/ios-11-tutorial-vision-framework-3c836d5ecadd

Code for the same is available here: **https://github.com/kravik/facevision**

[image: Lips detected using vision kit in my App]

Comment: please show what you have tried already and some code, it helps to give as much detail as possible

Comment: Added links for the code and tutorial that I followed

Comment: did you get any sulution? I have to do the same. @Mathew

Comment: try to create shaplayer b/w all points of lips then fill the clour